# Is there any difference for using 連用形 vs 連体形 when listing 形容動詞 to modify a 名詞?

Tags: conjugations, na-adjectives

E.g.

> 危険な投機的な事業
>
> 危険で投機的な事業

Are they both grammatical and mean the exact same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean "risky **and** speculative", then you should say 危険**で**投機的な, because that's one of dedicated meaning 連用形 has.

Saying 「危険な、投機的な事業」 (putting a comma is a good practice) for this meaning is not prohibited, but it either sounds like adding words one by one while you're speaking, which isn't very nice for written language; or could mean "risky **or** speculative".

Otherwise, 危険な投機的な事業 might well be interpreted as "risky speculative business", that is, 危険な modifies all what comes after.