# 連用修飾語 with で particle

Tags: grammar, particle-で

I've been reading an [article](http://xn--vcs415akpfnn7a.com/%E9%80%A3%E7%94%A8%E4%BF%AE%E9%A3%BE%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF.html) about 連用修飾語 when I noticed the following lines -

> 「サルビアの花は真っ赤で美しい。」
>
> 「美しい」が形容詞だというのが分かりますか？ **これを修飾するのは、「真っ赤で」になります**ね。つまり、「真っ赤で」が連用修飾語ということになります。

If I'm understanding correctly the author says that in this sentence 真っ赤 modifies 美しい. However, as far as I know, in order to modify 美しい the particle に should be written before 真っ赤 - 真っ赤に美しい. And で in 真っ赤で美しい is used to split two adjective - "Salvian flower is deep red and beautiful.". Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding something?

Since I think that the subject is similar, I would like to ask one more question. I'm interesed in the 平凡で埋没している part in the following sentence. Is で particle used to split 平凡 and 埋没している in the following sentence?

> まず、ただでさえジョン・ウェインのような突出したスターが起用されていない上に、キャラクターがどれも**平凡で埋没している**のがよくない。

Comment: I think [I've answered one](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24830/7810), but I don't believe it's the only question about this topic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you; I would interpret this sentence about サルビア as "red and beautiful", where 真っ赤 and 美しい are connected in parallel. 真っ赤に美しい (redly beautiful?) doesn't make sense to me, but grammatically, that should be how 真っ赤 can adverbially modify 美しい.

The same goes for 平凡で埋没している. It's just "キャラクターが平凡だ and キャラクターが埋没している".